# Make Names all in uppercase?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `Employee`, one column in this table named `Name`. The `Name` column is already filled with data (employee name). But some of these names are in uppercase letters and the other are in lowercase. How can I make them all in uppercase?

I am using Postgresql 9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`upper` to convert to uppercase

```
update Employee
set Name=upper(Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `upper (string)` function as seen [here](http://coderlearner.com/PostgreSQL_UPPER)